# Getting NoClassDefFoundError for an included jar

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jar

I'm writing a java app and running it on a linux ec2 server.
the program was running fluently yesterday, and after I changed and organazied some files and packages I'm getting this problem when I execute the program:

I'm running the programm with this command:

```
java -cp . main.Server
```

And get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
    at main.Group.<init>(Group.java:28)
    at main.Server.run(Server.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 2 more
```

I was running the programm as this before the changes:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/ec2-user/java-json.jar
```

In the bin folder, command:

```
java Server
```

And the programm was running.
Since I changed the package from default name to `main`, I need to run it with the command `java -cp . main.Server`, but I get the error written above.

I also tried modifing the `.bash_profile` and add this:

```
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/ec2-user/java-json.jar
export CLASSPATH
```

But it didn't help.
 I have no errors in my code and the jar is not broken since it worked before. What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the jar file on the classpath like this:

```
java -cp .:/home/ec2-user/java-json.jar main.Server
```

If your classpath is indeed correctly set in your `.bash_profile`, you could also do:

```
java -cp .:$CLASSPATH main.Server
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Do you know a way to include the jar without writing it in the command every execution?

Edit: Yea the second command works great. Thanks!

Comment: You could use something like the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to build an executable [JAR file that includes all dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies).